# Need an API to verify a stored credit card using cvv or transaction password before using it

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm in the middle of integrating the Paypal payments with in my application using the sandbox account. So when making the payment with the stored credit card is there any way to verify it using cvv by calling Paypal REST API before proceeding to payment?

While making payment using a stored credit card using REST API the cvv is not required, its already saved with the card, and only the saved id of the card is required to use a stored credit card. So in this scenario how can I verify that the particular user is authorized to use the stored card, and is there any REST API to do the verification of the card either with cvv or any transaction password as an extra level of security.

Also I tried to store a credit card without the cvv using REST API, its working but when I use this card for payment without the cvv its didn't thrown any error and the payment was successful . Why its like that? Do I need to enter the correct cvv to make payment? Or in the sandbox account is the cvv validation is disabled?

Please help.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On sandbox, you can set any CVV it will always work. There is no credit card validation. You can use any credit card number with the end date and CVV you want.

I guess you are using the Vault REST API? This API give you the option to store sensitive details like credit card related details on the PayPal server.

If you want to add extra security you could ask the user to type the credit card number again and use the lookup API to validate the number.

```
 GET /v1/vault/credit-cards/credit_card_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm using the Vault REST API. Definitely I will try out as you suggested. And I'm not marking this answer as a best one because I'm expecting for some other suggestions too. Anyway, you gave me a good suggestion, so thanks again.

Comment: I tried saving a card to paypal vault and then done look up on the same card. But the card number is given as"XXXXXXX" in the look up response due to security reasons. So I cant use this approach to provide extra level of security.

Comment: Yes you cannot reverse a card_id to get the card number. This is done by paypal for security reasons. So instead of entering card number everytime a payment is done, card_id (card token) will be used to make the payment instead of the card number.